# Should I use mocking, or Enzyme with shallow?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I have studying React for a couple of weeks now and I have just started to get into the Unit testing part. 
I am quite confused tho as there are very little standards when it comes to testing. 
I have seen that a lot of people opt for 'Jest' so this is the path that I chose too.
Since I am working with ES6 classes in my code, I can't just export the methods, I export the component classes. 
The code here is my testing case which works fine, but I don't want to build bad practices from the go:

```
import Calc from './Calc';
import React from 'react';
import {configure, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const wrapper = shallow(<Calc />);

const calculator = wrapper.instance();


test('Parentheses should close and evaluate automatically',() => {
    calculator.clear();
    const start = ['2','*(', '2', '+', '2'];


    for (let i = 0; i < start.length; i++) {
        calculator.addSign(start[i]);
    }
    calculator.calculate()

    expect(calculator.state.answ).toBe(8);

});
```

And this is part of the Calc component(the function which is to be evaluated):

```
class Calc extends React.Component{

state = {
    answ: 0,
    sumToEval: [],
    sumToShow:'',
}

calculate = () => {
    try{
        let sum = '';
        let bClose = false;
        let bStartingIndex = -1;
        let openCount = 0;
        let closeCount = 0;
        let closeString = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.sumToEval.length; i++) {
            if (this.state.sumToEval[i].indexOf('(') > -1) {
                if(bStartingIndex === -1) {
                    bStartingIndex = i;
                }
                openCount++;
            }
        }
        if (bStartingIndex > -1) {
            bClose = true;
            for (let i = bStartingIndex; i < this.state.sumToEval.length; i++) {
                if ( this.state.sumToEval[i].indexOf(')') > -1 ) {
                    bClose = false;
                    closeCount ++;
                }
            }
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < openCount-closeCount; i++) {
            closeString += ')';
        }



        // eslint-disable-next-line
        this.state.sumToEval.map((val) => {sum += val;})
        let answ;
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        bClose ? answ = eval(sum + closeString) : answ = eval(sum);
        console.log(answ);
        this.setState((prevState) =>{
            if (!bClose) {
                return {
                    answ: answ,
                    sumToEval: [answ + ''],
                    sumToShow: answ
                }
            }else{

                let tempArr = prevState.sumToEval;
                tempArr.push(')');
                return{
                    answ: answ,
                    sumToEval: [answ + ''],
                    sumToShow: answ
                }
            }

        });

    }catch(err){
      //  console.log(err);
        throw err;
    }
}
```

So is this the proper approach or is mocking the components always the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

> Since I am working with ES6 classes in my code, I can't just export the functions, I export the component classes.

I think there is a misunderstanding. Not everything needs to be a react component. Having function on their own is totally fine. In fact functions are better, because they are easier to reuse, easier to test and not tightly coupled to your view library (react).